# Hibernate - ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save()

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

We have following error

```
org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: 
ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save():
com.somepage.entity.MyObject
```

and code

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MYOBJECT")
public class MyObject{

private String myId;
private String title;

@Id
@Column(name = "MYID", unique = true, nullable = false)
public String getId() {
    return this.myId;
}

public void setVin(String vin) {
    this.vin = vin;
}

@Column(name = "TITLE", length = 10)
public String getTitle() {
    return this.title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
}
```

I have an entity where I enter (in the form, from webpage) data to the object including the ID. Is it necessary to get a GeneratorValue? How do I enter my ID by myself (without any unnecessary stuff)? Any ideas?

Comment: you need to set generation strategy to auto

Comment: @Antoniossss provide an answer...

Comment: @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO), effect ->

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist... any ideas?

Comment: Check that you have indeed a non-null ID in your entity when save() is called. You must not use GeneratedValue if you intend to provide the ID yourself. Also, the setter for the ID is lacking, and the setVin() method uses a field that doesn't exist.

Comment: JB Nizet, you're right, the returned object of the form (after entering ID) it doesnt contain ID! (just null).

Comment: how can I get around this? to the returned object was not empty?

Comment: I would add that I have another class where it is GeneratedValue and this works great (adds anything to the base what it wants)